# Logging into Heroku Fails - shell access

Tags: shell, heroku

O.k. so maybe I'm missing something basic here, but when I run heroku login I get the usual email and password prompt.

At this point I would assume I'm logged into the Heroku dino just a I would using my local box.

Instead I get a message telling me I'm logged in, but I'm still on my local box.

Is there really no shell access for Heroku apps?

Comment: what exactly do you need to do on heroku? eg: `mysql`... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a dynamic session with this command:

`heroku run bash`

However, please be aware that Heroku runs applications on dynos: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. basically for anyone who deals with this after me, why i want shell access is to change important keys (db, secret_key, etc.) from the command line and not change the files and allow them to be in github without any worries...hope this helps someone.

Comment: just realized changes using this are temporary...so it's good to know this works...but it's not the real thing

Comment: If you go to `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/settings` and set an config variable, it will stay permanent, being set as environment variable every time a dyno is started. That's where secret keys are typically kept.

Comment: You can also set them via CLI with `heroku config:set`

Answer (score 0):

`heroku login` doesn't open a new terminal session like `ssh` would. Instead, it just remembers your profile so that when you call `heroku` with a different command (like `heroku create` to create a new app) you won't be prompted for email and password again.

You can also push your code to the app with `git push heroku master` once you are logged in.

You can do some hackery (like using [this plugin](https://github.com/fabiokung/heroku-ssh)) to `ssh` into your dyno, but that's not the way `heroku` is supposed to work. The idea behind `heroku` is that you just push your code there and it manages everything else for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't directly access the Heroku dynos. You can run commands through the CLI, such as getting logs, adding add-ins, etc.

Logging in through the CLI, as you have done, is simply setting your credentials for Heroku locally.  They are subsequently used for running commands so you don't always have to reauthenticate.